# Action button using flutter_local_notifications package

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

**When the app is live or debugign mode**

[image: push notification]

**when app in forground and background**

[image: push notification]

**I am using this sample code**

`NotificationDetails( android: AndroidNotificationDetails( channel3.id, channel3.name, playSound: true, channelDescription: channel3.description, priority: Priority.high, importance: Importance.high, icon: '@mipmap/launcher_icon', actions: [ AndroidNotificationAction('action_1', 'Action 1', showsUserInterface: true), AndroidNotificationAction('action_2', 'Action 2', showsUserInterface: true), ], ),),`

**I am using flutter_local_notifications package once the terminates it does not show the action button on notification. i am using firebase cloud messing for push notification**